# How to drop last row where a field contains None?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id_": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "date": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
        "existing": ["Y", "Y", None, "Y", None, None, "Y"],
    }
)
```

I would like to drop the last row where `existing` equals `None`. I've tried the following:

```
df = df.drop(df[df["existing"] is None].tail(1).index)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
False
```

Where am I going wrong? It would be great if someone could explain why so I can learn the logic behind the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should do `isnull` or `isna`

```
df = df.drop(df.index[df.existing.isnull()][-1])
Out[175]: 
   id_  date existing
0    1     1        Y
1    2     2        Y
2    3     2     None
3    4     3        Y
4    5     3     None
6    7     4        Y
```

Fix your code

```
df.drop(df[[x is None for x in df["existing"]]].tail(1).index)
Out[177]: 
   id_  date existing
0    1     1        Y
1    2     2        Y
2    3     2     None
3    4     3        Y
4    5     3     None
6    7     4        Y
```

Comment: `df["existing"]` is a pandas series, `df["existing"] is None` translates to `False`. You don't have a column named `False`, so `df[df["existing"] is None]` returns `Keyerror`.

Comment: @Jossy df["existing"] is None is check every cell, but you passed a column to it , it will not out the result , you can do for loop `[x is None for x in df["existing"]]`